# add component in experience editor not working

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

I am trying to add a component in experience editor in sxa project. On clicking add here button, the below popup is coming
[image]

I am expecting this list of available rendering

[image]

is there any configuration setting that I can check?

Comment: Did you add your components in the specific module?

Comment: It's showing on every page, i did not change any component it was working fine till yesterday but showing this behaviour after deployment. Is there any settings that i can check?

Comment: You should start by looking at the placeholder settings item that is being used here. For configurations, you should check what has changed in your solution since you deployed it last time. It can give you pointers on why this issue is occurring.

Answer (score -1):

To see your rendering in the select a rendering popup, you can check and verify the following things.

- **Check Allowed Renderings**: Ensure that the rendering you want to add is included in the allowed renderings for the specific placeholder settings. Navigate to the item's Presentation Details, and in the Allowed Renderings section, verify that the rendering is listed.
- **Available Rendering**: Check the you have added in the available rendering section like below

[image]

- **Placeholder Key**: Confirm that the placeholder key used in the rendering definition matches the placeholder key in the placeholder settings. They should be identical for the rendering to be available in that placeholder.

Refer this for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/walkthrough--building-a-simple-rendering.html

Hope this helps.